# How to use the information on a Google Sheet to call a PATCH API on a remote server

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to discern what would be the best approach to do this. I have a Google Sheet with a long list of serial numbers attached to identifiers. I have an API which allows me to PATCH each entry (each identifier) with their corresponding serial numbers.

I could call the API one at a time for each entry, but that would drive me crazy and be prone to errors. I could also maybe create a BASH script and cURL my way through the list somehow.

I would however much rather create a script (I think I could do this on google sheets directly using Google Apps Scripts) that reads the column with the identifier and sends an API PATCH to the server with the corresponding serial number.

I found [this tutorial](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/api-tutorial-for-beginners/) to make API GET queries to databases, but I would like to know how to do this with PATCH and PUT. Also I need to authenticate, but that's already explained in the comments of the above tutorial. I am happy being pointed to some tutorial or some lines of code that will allow me to perform this operations automated.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you are on the right track using Google Apps Script to do this.

You can make any type of requests using [`UrlFetchApp.fetch()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) not only GET requests. You need to configure your options accordingly and pass them in the request.

And since you would be using GAS it is simple to get the data from the sheet using the [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet).

You could either build execute each request in a for loop or create all the requests as JavaScript objects and use [`UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)

Apart from avoiding coding OAuth flow into an app, by using GAS you also have the added benefit of having the [Stackdriver logging](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging#stackdriver_logging), and access to many other basic and advanced [G Suite Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference) such as (Calendar, Gmail, Sheets, Slides, Meet, Drive, Forms, Maps, etc.). Apps Script is a great tool to connect many Google Products.